# Using jQuery .live with toggle event

Tags: jquery

My code is working, but requiring me to click twice to active my chaining (once for the click event, and once for the toggle event.) What can I do to make it so I only have to click once so that the toggle will automatically occur?

```
    //Show or Hide Comments
$('#showHideComments').live('click', function() {
    $('#showHideComments').toggle(function() {
        $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "+=53px"}, 500);
        $("#comments").fadeIn(300);
        $("#addComment").fadeIn(300);
    },function(){
        $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "-=53px"}, 500);
        $("#comments").fadeOut(300);
        $("#addComment").fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You cannot use `live` and `toggle` together. What you can do, is simply make your own "toggle" of sorts:

```
$('#showHideComments').live('click', function() {
    if($("#addComment").is(':visible')){
      $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "-=53px"}, 500);
      $("#comments, #addComment").fadeOut(300);
    } else {
      $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "+=53px"}, 500);
      $("#comments, #addComment").fadeIn(300);
    };
});
```

`live` is binding to `click`, however, when `toggle` is called, it is also bound (normally) on click. You should decide if 'live' is really what you need. For instance, if `#showHideComments` object is replaced via AJAX during the use of the page, then you need live and my solution. However, if it isn't swapped out and remains the same, just use the inside of your original `live` function (just the toggle code) and you will be golden.

Comment: Pssst, combine selectors too!

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. I do need to use live as the data is returned by my php script via ajax. Thanks for the optimization too, I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 4):

```
//Show or Hide Comments
$('#showHideComments').live('click', function() {
    $('#showHideComments').toggle(function() {
        $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "+=53px"}, 500);
        $("#comments").fadeIn(300);
        $("#addComment").fadeIn(300);
    },function(){
        $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "-=53px"}, 500);
        $("#comments").fadeOut(300);
        $("#addComment").fadeOut(300);
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

This will also work :)

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, use $(this) for the toggle so it refers to the parent - this will work better with multiple instances based on classes or unique objects referred by ID at the parent:

```
$('#showHideComments').live('click', function() {
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "+=53px"}, 500);
        $("#comments").fadeIn(300);
        $("#addComment").fadeIn(300);
    },function(){
        $(".commentsSwitch").animate({"marginLeft": "-=53px"}, 500);
        $("#comments").fadeOut(300);
        $("#addComment").fadeOut(300);
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`live` is deprecated. Use `on` instead
For instance:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'a[data-object="save-post"]', () ->
  alert 'Saving the post...'
```