# jQuery strategy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-events

I have migrated frameworks from prototype to jQuery in my Rails apps, and I'm running into a consistent problem which I need some advice on.

Often times I'll use an AJAX function that updates a portion of the page.  When this happens, any other Javascript I use that relates to the section of the page that was updated no longer works.  What's the best way around this?

Most of my Javascript lives inside `jQuery(document).ready(function() { });` with some functions that live outside this method. I've been getting around this by relying on the jQuery `.live()` handler, or by calling the function I want to 'reinitialize' in my js.erb files.

What's the best approach?  Should I:

- explicitly call functions by name to work as part of the callback to get them to work
- continue to use the `.live()` for submit/click events
- or is there better, more efficient way to deal with this

Looking forward to your feedback everyone and thanks for your advice.

Comment: I'm not understanding how the question about calling functions outside `.ready()` by name relates to using `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

aressidi - you could also use .livequery() as this encapsulates .live() with a few additional bells and whistles for callbacks etc. also, consider using .unbind() for certain event handlers (such as toggle etc).

more info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

jim

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your response.  I got things mostly working based on your answer and nicholasklick's below.  I realized that it was toggle that was causing problems after replacing a portion of the page with AJAX.  I found a post on how to create your own toggle handler and encapsulate it in .live().  Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172614/using-jquery-live-with-toggle-event.  The only problem is that it only works for one cycle - show and hide.  If I click it again, nothing happens.  Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0):

In your callbacks use trigger() to trigger events. Use live() for events bound to areas of the DOM that are being updated.

I always use this pattern:

Ajax:

```
$(.link).live("click", function(){
  $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action',
        success: function(response){
        $(document).trigger("event_name", ["method", response]);
        $('.class').html(response.html);
        }
    }); 
})
```

Rails action (rerender content of a partial):

```
class Controller < ApplicationController

def action
    render :json => {
          :html => render_to_string(
            :partial => 'partial_name', 
            :locals => {:var => @var}
          )
        }
end
```

Comment: Hi Nicholasklick, thanks for your answer.  I posted a follow-up under Jim's answer above that you might be able to help with as well.  Both of your answers have come in handy.  Thanks again