# Working with a clone() menu on jQuery to load a menu from PHP

Tags: jquery, toggle, clone, live

Based in this ex. [How to use toggle event with live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841788/how-to-use-toggle-event-with-live/3842172#3842172) I'm trying to get working this code on a clone() menu which stays always on top as in this ex. http://jsfiddle.net/fj8wM/181/ the original worked fine, but the cloned one does not work as well.

```js
$("#showmenu").live('click', function () {
    var toggled = $('#menudiv').data('toggled');
        $('#menudiv').data('toggled', !toggled);
            if (!toggled) {
              setCookie('show_menu','1','1');
              $('#showmenu').html('Hide menu');
              $('#menudiv').slideDown();
              $('#menudiv div').load('menu.php');
    } else {
              $('#menudiv').slideUp();
              $('#menudiv').remove('#menudiv div');
              setCookie('show_menu','','');
              $('#showmenu').html('Show menu');   
    }
}); 
      
    var cmenu = getCookie('show_menu');
        if(cmenu){
        $('#showmenu').html('Hide menu');
        $('#menudiv').load('menu.php');
        $('#menudiv').show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Are you referring to alert not triggering when you click the link? Just replace this:</strike>

```
$('#login').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

with this:

```
$('#login').live('click', function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

**UPDATE:** this is more of a hack, it can certainly be tidied up but I think it does what you wanted. I had to change the html slightly as well as js: http://jsfiddle.net/fDgke/3/

Comment: @gonis - not in the example on fiddler you provided, could you provide the link with complete code you are working on?

Comment: more or less. but still some bugs remain as show/hide text :(. Anyway thnx u very much for your help.

Comment: Which bugs? Let me know if something's not working, I can fix that for you.

Comment: when page is not scrolled "show or hide" text change but if you scroll it is not the same on cloned menu (ex. show is hide or vs)

Comment: the problem is because I want to load() a menu. In jsfiddle we have use a ready menu. If you see in my first post (question) I use a loading menu (menu.php) and there are difference between ready menu and a load menu.

Comment: @gonis - so does my answer provide a working solution or is there anything else I can help you with? You might want to considering uploading the app somewhere so I could see what's actually going on in your code.