# how to set jquery toggle position after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle, live

I am setting up a mining calculator for a game called eve.

In my calculator you can select from a list of players and then from a list of ore.

As you select a player or ore, a toggle event is used in jquery to signal to the player that he/she has selected the item.  In addition an ajax call to a php script is fired to add/delete member/ore from a database.

The issue I have is that although when the mining op is loaded that has previously been worked on (has already had members/ore added to it) the toggle events for the player/ore are still set as if it has not been selected.  I already have php code in place that prevents adding duplicate players and ore but I would like the interface to show to the user that a player or ore has previously been selected.  Additionally as the player / ore has already been selected in a previous session, I would like the first action of the toggle event to be the one that would be used to unhighlight the selection and remove the ore.

Every ore that is part of the op that is stored in the db is returned with a rel tag with its typeId 
Below is a sample of what the player list looks like:

```
<div class="miningMemberList">
    <div class="float" style="color: whitesmoke;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="option1" value="90892149" style="display: none; ">Glitch Rin
    </div>
    <div class="float" style="color: whitesmoke;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="option1" value="1162532926" style="display: none; ">Drake Firerain
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is a sample of what the ore list looks like:

```
<div class="oreList" style="display: block; ">
    <div class="opOre" typeid="17428">
        Triclinic Bistot<img class="img_opOre" src="http://image.eveonline.com/Type/17428_32.png" alt="Triclinic Bistot">
    </div>
    <div class="opOre" typeid="17429">
        Monoclinic Bistot<img class="img_opOre" src="http://image.eveonline.com/Type/17429_32.png" alt="Monoclinic Bistot">
    </div>
    <div class="opOre" typeid="1227" style="background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57); color: rgb(245, 245, 245); ">
        Omber<img class="img_opOre" src="http://image.eveonline.com/Type/1227_32.png" alt="Omber">
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is a sample of the returned data from the ajax calls.

```
<div id="opTableContainer">
    <from>
    <table border="1" id="returnTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th display="true" rel="17428">
            <img class="img_opOre" src="http://image.eveonline.com/Type/17428_32.png" alt="Triclinic Bistot">Triclinic Bistot
        </th>
        <th display="true" rel="17429">
            <img class="img_opOre" src="http://image.eveonline.com/Type/17429_32.png" alt="Monoclinic Bistot">Monoclinic Bistot
        </th>
        <th display="true" rel="1227">
            <img class="img_opOre" src="http://image.eveonline.com/Type/1227_32.png" alt="Omber">Omber
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/redXblackBackground.png" style="float: left;">Player 1
        </td>
        <td rel="17428">
            <input type="text" style="width:100px" name="17428">
        </td>
        <td rel="17429">
            <input type="text" style="width:100px" name="17429">
        </td>
        <td rel="1227">
            <input type="text" style="width:100px" name="1227">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/redXblackBackground.png" style="float: left;">Player 2
        </td>
        <td rel="17428">
            <input type="text" style="width:100px" name="17428">
        </td>
        <td rel="17429">
            <input type="text" style="width:100px" name="17429">
        </td>
        <td rel="1227">
            <input type="text" style="width:100px" name="1227">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit"></from>
</div>
```

Below is a sample of what the javascript looks like for the toggle event for the ore.  The toggle event for the players is nearly the same.

```
$(".opOre").toggle(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','#393939');
        $(this).css('color','whitesmoke');
        var urlQuery = location.search;
    urlQuery = urlQuery.replace('?', '');
    var getVariable = urlQuery.split('=');
    typeId = $(this).attr('typeid');
    //split[0] is your var name, and split[1]
    /* ADD ORE TO OP TO DB */
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "thePHPManagementScript.php",
        data: { action : 'addOre', opId : getVariable[1], typeId : typeId },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#opTableContainer").empty();
            $("#opTableContainer").append(data); 
            var bodyRows = $("#returnTable tbody tr");
            bodyRows.each(function(){
                var firstCell = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
                console.log(firstCell);
                $("#opSelectBox option").filter(function() { 
                    return this.text == firstCell; 
                }).remove();
            });
        }
        });
    },function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','black');
        var urlQuery = location.search;
    urlQuery = urlQuery.replace('?', '');
    var getVariable = urlQuery.split('=');
    typeId = $(this).attr('typeid');
    /* REMOVE ORE FROM OP FROM DB */
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "thePHPManagementScript.php",
        data: { action : 'removeOre', opId : getVariable[1], typeId : typeId },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#opTableContainer").empty();
            $("#opTableContainer").append(data); 
            var bodyRows = $("#returnTable tbody tr");
            bodyRows.each(function(){
                var firstCell = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
                console.log(firstCell);
                $("#opSelectBox option").filter(function() { 
                    return this.text == firstCell; 
                }).remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

With any luck I have asked this question in a way that is understandable.

I know what ever I do is probably going to have to be done in the success: part of the ajax request, I just dont know how to go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link where I could view the problem, having a bit of trouble mentally visualising based on the description. I've had problems with dynamically loaded content in the past and could be something as simple as adding .live() to the toggle so that it works on loaded content.

Comment: It would be difficult to show you a real life example as that would require creating an account on the site, and you have to be a member of our corp in game in order to even register.  Additionally you must be the owner of the mining op to view it if it is still active.  Do you know how to set which of the toggle function is to be used next?  This i think will solve the issue as I need to have the returned data scanned then set the visual selection on the appropriate player/ore tables then need to set the toggle event to fire the second function rather than the first.

Comment: If I could talk with you in a more private area than this, I could reset my password and allow access.

Comment: I think I follow, you want it to know which toggle to use after content has been loaded? either add or remove ore?

Comment: I would suggest moving away from the toggle function you might find this post useful (if I understand the problem correctly)...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841788/how-to-use-toggle-event-with-live

Comment: It appears as though this is just a plain javascript version of toggle.  It will present the same issue.

Comment: Try using a cookie or session variable to store the toggle state.

Comment: I solved the issue by not using the toggle event and am testing for an attribute that is set instead.