# Ajax call is breaking Jquery toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, toggle

I have a basic toggle function, when item is clicked initially it sends an ajax post, and when clicked the second time it sends a second different ajax post.

the issue is once it makes the ajax call, the second toggle function no longer fires.

When I removed the ajax functions from the toggle and replaced them with a basic show/hide div, it worked just fine first and second click.

Below is my code:

You will notice I have a basic show/hide function for the first click, for testing purposes. Using this code the first click works, second click works and make the ajax call, but any clicks after dont do anything.

```
//Sort by Instrument ACS or DESC
$("th#seeking").toggle(function()

  { // first click update sorting order


 $("a.add_listing").hide(200);
 $("a.add_listing").show(200);

  },
  function()
  { // On second Click toggle opposite sorting order


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_calls.php",
        data: "order=instrument_asc&sort_item=true",
        success: function(r){$("#listings").html(r);},
        error: function(){alert(2);$("#error").text("Could not retrieve posts").fadeIn(300).delay(900).fadeOut(300)}
    })





  });
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Do you get an error on the console?

Comment: Is the table header *inside* whatever "#listings" is?  In other words, is the AJAX response replacing the HTML for which your toggle was set up in the first place?

Comment: @felix No errors showing in firbug. Just after the second click any further clicks do nothing.

Comment: @pointy you are right it is. Ah so it can no longer find the selector? Is there a way to make the click again within the ajax results?

Comment: Well instead of binding the event handler with "toggle", you can set it up with ".delegate()" or ".live()" (I prefer the former).

Comment: @pointy Thanks. Can you provide me with sample code doing that? (yes strong jquery noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the portion of the page containing the element that's clicked is replaced by the AJAX results, then the handler will be lost.  You could do something like this instead:

```
$(function() {
  var toggleState = 0;
  $('body').delegate('th#seeking', 'click', function() {
    if (toggleState === 0) {
      $("a.add_listing").hide(200);
      $("a.add_listing").show(200);
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_calls.php",
        data: "order=instrument_asc&sort_item=true",
        success: function(r){$("#listings").html(r);},
        error: function(){
          alert(2);
          $("#error").text("Could not retrieve posts")
            .fadeIn(300).delay(900).fadeOut(300)
        }
      });
    }
    toggleState = toggleState ^ 1;
  });
});
```

That sets up a "click" handler and keeps track of the toggle state explicitly, but it makes the handler work on the event as it bubbles up to the `<body>` (you could put the handler at a closer container in the DOM if you wanted to).  Thus even if you replace the page fragment, as long as the new fragment has that "id" value on the table header, the delegated event handler will "see" it.

*edit* — I changed that slightly to indicate that this should be done in a "ready" handler, or in some other way such that the `<body>` element exists in the DOM.  If the code were to run in a `<script>` block in the `<head>` without being set up as a "ready" or "load" handler, then the `<body>` won't be there and it won't do anything.

*edit again* — [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vJqMX/) is a faked-up demo.  There was a big in my code above (missing "})" towards the end) that I've fixed in that fiddle, and that I'll fix here too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that does make sense. One issue though, the above code it not working for me. Do I need to attach the above function to an onlclick event or such?

Comment: Well that "delegate" call should be setting up the handler.  Unfortunately (because of the ajax part) it's sort of tricky to show this working in a jsfiddle.  The code should probably be run in a jQuery "ready" handler; I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks again. I have it within a document.ready function. I am seeing an error in firebug when I add the above code stating "missing } after function body" I tried adding in the missing bracket, and the error leaves but the code still does not work. Any Ideas? Thanks again for your time and help

Comment: If you could show it working in jsfiddle (without the ajax, just show/hide functions) That would be really helpfull, as I could probably take it from there.

Comment: @Levi - sorry about that but I had a minor error in the code :-) It's fixed [in the jsfiddle I hacked up](http://jsfiddle.net/vJqMX/)

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought using jquery.live() would be a good solution, like the answer seen here:
[Using jQuery .live with toggle event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172614/using-jquery-live-with-toggle-event)