# Jquery function problem

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with this Jquery function.
The the simplifide code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".brs").toggle(function() {
        var commid=$(this).attr('kid');
        $('.comment'+commid).html('the new text - <a href="javascript: void(0)"  class="brs2" kid="'+ commid +'">click to change the text</a>');
    }, function () {
        var commid=$(this).attr('kid');
        $('.comment'+commid).html('new text');
    });

    $(".brs2").click(function() {
        alert("test"); 
    });

});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="comment1">some text</div> | <a href="javascript: void(0)"  class="brs" kid="1">test link</a>
```

When the text changes in the div "comment1" the link that runs another function (class "brs2") does not work. What could be the problem?

Thanks for all sugestions.

EDIT:

If the Jquery code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".brs").toggle(function() {
var commid=$(this).attr('kid');
$('.comment'+commid).html('the new text - <a href="javascript: void(0)"  class="brs" kid="'+ commid +'">click to change the text</a>');
}, function () {
var commid=$(this).attr('kid');
$('.comment'+commid).html('new text');
});

$(".brs2").click(function() {
alert("test"); 
});

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="comment1">some text</div> | <a href="javascript: void(0)"  class="brs" kid="1">test link</a>
```

I can't use live() to trigger the same toggle function with new link that appears in comment1 div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `live` instead of `click` because you are dynamically inserting the link in the `DOM`

```
$(".brs2").live('click',function() {
alert("test");
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7E8aG/1/

here is a link to jquery `live` http://api.jquery.com/live/

**Edit**

if i have understood well may be you can do it like

```
$(".brs2").live('click',function() {
    if($(this).is(':visible'))
    {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        $("div.comment1").html("new text");
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7E8aG/2/

Answer (score 3):

Because the link (.brs2) isn't in DOM when the page is loaded. You have to [`live();`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) bind the `click` event.

```
$('.brs2').live('click', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

You could as well use [`delegate();`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), but that's an overkill for such a simple task and a bit more complicated.

#### Update

If I understood the question correctly, you can bind multiple events on `live` or you can `delegate` them. Please see the post here - [Using jQuery .live with toggle event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172614/using-jquery-live-with-toggle-event) - it should give you the information you're looking for. I can provide the answer only tomorrow, it's late here.

Answer (score 0):

Or do:

```
$('.comment'+commid+' .brs2').click(function() {
        alert("test"); 
});
```

after html manipulation in first toggle function