# jQuery custom toggle between divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle, toggleclass

having some trouble with this can't understand why it won't work properly.

http://host.philmadelphia2.com/~clare/order/

when you click the two "order..." links at the top, they should toggle between divs. When the one page is active, clicking on that page's button shouldn't have any effect. There should only be an action when the unactive page's button is clicked.

Here is the link to the JS.

http://host.philmadelphia2.com/~clare/wp-content/themes/theme/js/pager.js

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI for the effects.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: link to the js does nt help.. can you update the question with part that is causing the prob

Comment: and also I would suggest host only the things related to your question on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw together a quick mockup on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MATW/2/) that seems to work. I've stripped out a lot of the markup to make it a bit easier to read.

The only changes I've made is to remove the $ sign in the function declarations and used the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) event handler instead of click().

Edit: For explanation purposes, since you are manipulating the DOM by adding and removing classes you have to use the live() event handler.

Comment: do you see any reason the UI blind effect isn't working on the site? thanks again for the live(), snippet

Comment: You cannot use live() and toggle() together. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172614/using-jquery-live-with-toggle-event)

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor selector is wrong. In your markup `unactive` class is applied to only one anchor on the page load so `a.unactive` will select only the anchor which has `unactive` class. You want to have `click` event attached to both the anchors so you should use `button` class which is applied to both the anchors. Try this

```
    jQuery('a.unactive').live(function($){
        jQuery('a.button').toggleClass('unactive');
        jQuery('div.page').toggle('blind','',500);
        console.log('clicked');
    });
```

Comment: if I do it this way, then both buttons will tigger the function, I only want the unactive button click to cause the transition

Answer (score 0):

If you keep clicking 'Order Samples', it is toggling the unactive class back and forth on all the a.buttons.

What you are basically looking for is a jQuery tabs script. In your case, the "tabs" are just text links. I recently used the [**idTabs** script](http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/#advanced) on a site with text tabs, and it worked pretty well.