# .on() & toggle working together

Tags: jquery, toggle

Quick question here guys, I cant seem to get this

```
$('#wrap').on('toggle', '#image', function(){
    <!-- Do stuff -->
  });
```

to be able to have a toggle inside it? Any ideas? I have tried googling but with no luck.

this is the code i am trying to get to work with .on, as currently it doesn't apply the changes to all of the element son the page, (that have #image and #brick)

```
$("#result_options").toggle(function() {
        var image_width = $('#image').width() / 2;
        var brick_width = $('#brick').width() / 2;
        $("#image").css("width",image_width);
        $("#image").css("padding","4px");
        $("#brick").css("width",brick_width);
    },function (){
        $("#image").css("width","300");
        $("#image").css("padding","8px");
        $("#brick").css("width","314");
        $(this).html("Smaller Results");
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery .live with toggle event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172614/using-jquery-live-with-toggle-event)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that there is no `toggle` event; `toggle()` is a jQuery method. To implement a `toggle()`, with `on()` I think you'd need to use a `click` event, and then an `if` statement to test whether something's been toggled on, or toggled-off/not-toggled

```
$('#wrap').on('click', '#image', function(){
    if (!$(this).attr('data-toggled') || $(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'off'){
        /* currently it's not been toggled, or it's been toggled to the 'off' state,
           so now toggle to the 'on' state: */
           $(this).attr('data-toggled','on');
           // and do something...
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'on'){
        /* currently it has been toggled, and toggled to the 'on' state,
           so now turn off: */
           $(this).attr('data-toggled','off');
           // and do, or undo, something...
    }
});
```

Comment: @maryisdead: thanks! I hadn't realised that (or I'd assumed it was used as a user-defined custom event). =)