# jQuery - add 2 buttons with parent().before() + parent.after() and use them later with .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is how I did it

```
//wrap a div arround the table
$(this).wrap('<div class="table_space"><div class="table_wrapper_div">
</div></div>').parent().before('<button class="my_button" >
EXPANDIR</button>').after('<button class="my_button">EXPANDIR</button>');
```

this = a very big table

```
$('.my_button').toggle(
        function(){ 
            ... blablabla ...
    },
    function(){ 
        ... blabllaba ...
    }
);
```

But the toggle event is never triggered... now if I add the button directly in the html page then the toggle event is in this case triggered.
Any help will be great, I've looked for other questions but didn't find any clue.
Thanks a lot

EDIT: NB - the wrapping gives exactly what I need and puts the buttons between table_space and table_wrapper_div

Comment: You should embed your title in code block tag, just a joke...

Comment: make sure your wrapper is created before you toggle event and also you might try using [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/): `$('.my_button').on("toggle", function ....`

Comment: +1 SpYk3HH I was going to write that as an answer ;-)

Comment: See there http://stackoverflow.com/a/10864408/1414562

Comment: @SpYk3HH tks for the input, The toggle event is indeed created after the wrapping... I'll check on .on()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **delegate** in such cases where the elements are dynamically added to your HTML ...

Internally the event is associated using a click event..

Try this approach

```
$('body').on('click', '.my_button', function() {
    $('.my_button').toggle(
          function(){ 
              ... blablabla ...
          },
          function(){ 
              ... blabllaba ...
          }
    );
});
```

Comment: sorry... didn't get what you meant

Comment: "Internally the event is associated using a click event.." I thought this too, but Not according to their [**latest docs**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/#entry-examples)