# Data value does not change in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I must have misunderstood, but I thought that the data-value of a HTML-element changes when calling the jQuery .data() function:

```
<div id="empty_column_0" data-name="empty_column_0" class="settings_toggle toggle-success inline-toggle" data-target="column_0" data-value="0"></div>
```

When I "toggle" this element, the data-value must change from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

I do this with:

```
$('.settings_toggle').on('toggle', function (e, active) 
{
    var that = $(e.target);  
    //Change the data value of the element
    if(active) {var bool = 1;} else {var bool = 0;}
    that.data('value', bool);
    console.log(that.data('value'));
});
```

The value changes in the console but not in the HTML?
Is this how it is suppose to work?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864353/on-toggle-working-together

Comment: I will leave the tags out next time:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. jQuery `data()` does not update the `data-` HTML attributes. If you wish to update the HTML attributes you'll need to use:

```
that.attr('data-value', bool);
```

Comment: @UnknownUser - Yes, and it doesn't update HTML `data-` attributes automatically like I stated and the OP asked...

Comment: @Shomz What? The HTML attributes are not updated in that JSFiddle you linked... And the docs don't mention updating the HTML attributes at all

Answer (score -1):

You code could work, please see the link to understand the difference between .data() and .attr():

1. https://api.jquery.com/data/#data1

> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   from memory leaks.

2. [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)