# Toggle not working for displaying alternate message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the messages 'Yes' and 'No' on the button click event, but that is currently not working with the below code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>
         </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="myButton">
            Button
        </button>
        <br />
        <span id="mySpan">          
        </span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS `custom.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').on('toggle',function(){
        $('#mySpan').html('Yes');
    },function(){
        $('#mySpan').html('No');
    });
});
```

Comment: I was unaware that 'toggle' was an event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.on() & toggle working together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864353/on-toggle-working-together)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `'toggle'` event - you can either use the jquery `.toggle()` function or use an `.on('click')` handler to then perform the toggle.

```
$( "#target" ).toggle(function() {
  alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
}, function() {
  alert( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
});
```

Comment: This was deprecated, you need to use jQuery before 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var $mySpan = $('#mySpan');
$('#myButton').on('click', function(){
  $mySpan.html( $mySpan.html() === 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">
  Button
</button>
<br />
<span id="mySpan">          
        </span>
```

Comment: That surely solves the problem, but how can I do that with `toggle`

Comment: @RK, use jQuery 1.8 or below.. - toggle() in newer versions of jquery doesn't work like that.... https://jsfiddle.net/m7gh3av0/2/

Comment: Yeah, i'm having issues getting it to work with toggle on later versions.  Must it be a toggle?

Comment: @Taplar, yes it is deprecated and removed as 'event': https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ New toggle method: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/ is related to visibility of elements.  I guess that OP was confused because of this.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't do anything on the first click because it's only attaching the event handler at that point.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
      
$("#mySpan").text() =="Yes"?    $('#mySpan').text('No'):$('#mySpan').text('Yes');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">
            Button
        </button>
        <br />
        <span id="mySpan">          
        </span>
```

Comment: I don't think this matches RK's intent.

Comment: ¡Excellente! Mas bueno.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `.click` event instead of `.on`.

Here is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mp5w4b8c/

And your jQuery should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        $('#mySpan').html('Yes');
    },function(){
        $('#mySpan').html('No');
    });
});
```

### Update:

I changed my jQuery logic to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        if($('#mySpan').html ===  "" || 'No') {
            $('#mySpan').html('Yes');
        } else if($('#mySpan').html === 'Yes') {
            $('#mySpan').html('No');
        }
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work as i expected. Is there any issues in my code?

The updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mp5w4b8c/

Comment: Nope, did you tested it?

Comment: I'll check the question again and will improve my answer

Comment: This version of toggle was deprecated.  You need to use a version of jQuery older than 1.9.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Yes, the issue is `$('#mySpan').html` is equal to a function, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

This works with toggle on the most recent version of jQuery.  `.toggle()` now only displays or hides an element.  There are various options you can use to control how that happens.  This example starts with all elements present, but one of them is not displayed via CSS.  jQuery `.toggle()` will toggle the display values on the elements with a class of `mySpan`.

```js
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  $('.mySpan').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>
         </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="myButton">
            Button
        </button>
        <br />
        <span class="mySpan">Yes</span>
        <span class="mySpan" style="display: none">No</span>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $elem = $('#mySpan'); 
$('#myButton').click(function(){ 
   $elem.html( $elem.text().trim() === 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes' ); 
});
```

This code should work fine for your case