# jQuery on('toggle') possible?

Tags: jquery, toggle

Instead of using `$('.element').toggle(function(){}, function(){});`

I would need to use the `.on()` method on the element I want to use `.toggle()` on but I can't figure out how to specify my second event handler function:

```
$('body').on('toggle', '.element', function(){});
```

Where would I have to specify the second handler function for my toggle event?

I did this here: http://jsfiddle.net/D33f4/ but nothing happens on the first click. I really don't understand why.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172614/using-jquery-live-with-toggle-event).

Comment: if i get it correctly, you are trying to do on toggle?

Comment: I did this here: http://jsfiddle.net/D33f4/ but nothing happens on the first click. I really don't understand why. Any idea?

Comment: you need to add document ready. http://jsfiddle.net/D33f4/1/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you use the existing `toggle()` function?

Comment: @EH_warch nothing happens on the first click, the alert doesn't popup
Aleks G: my clickable elements are added "on the fly", that's why I need the .on method

Comment: @Vincent totally right i didnt notice it was working on the second click and foward

Comment: @EH_warch Mario Cesar explained why nothing happens on the first click. Do you know if using "toggle" in .on is only possible? Or do I absolutely have to go through "click" and then attach the toggle event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using only the toggle.

```
$('#clickme').toggle(
    function(){alert('click 1');},
     function(){alert('click 2');}
);
```

As it is, it doesn't do anything on the first click because it's only attaching the event handler at that point.

EDIT:

I didn't fully read the post. My bad.

```
$('body').on('click', '#clickme', function()
{
    var state = $(this).data('state');


    switch(state){
        case 1 :
        case undefined : alert('click 1'); $(this).data('state', 2); break;
        case 2 : alert('click 2'); $(this).data('state', 1); break;
    }
});
```

Comment: On the answer he specifies `Instead of using $('.element').toggle(function(){}, function(){});`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I was straight to the jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you, I did not get the subtility of why nothing happened on the first click. However, I am very surprised there is no way to use .toggle and .on together. Am I wrong?

Comment: I believe you are correct. At least i don't know any way to delegate the toggle, I'll leave the confirmation to some kind of jquery guru :)

Comment: Will it act as `.live()`? This function will work with elements added after `$(document).ready()` was triggered?

Comment: It will act, if used like that, as the old .delegate() function.
From the docs "Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements."

Comment: For any future visitors to this page - .toggle() event handler is deprecated in v1.8 and removed in v1.9. 
https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
  $("#chkShowDevices").click(function() {
    console.log($("#chkShowDevices").prop("checked"));
  });
```