# How to change on click to toggle ? - hide element on unbind button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, toggle

I get this code (it is not written by me)

Problem that I am not able to solve is:

To hide that iframe - I need to click the same button again and I would like to hide it on clicking somewhere else - something like toggle()

For now I tried to create new code with toggle, but I had problems with getting the right id, which is saved in clicked button id,

I also tried to base my new code on answer here :

[.on() & toggle working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864353/on-toggle-working-together) 
and [jQuery on('toggle') possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579017/jquery-ontoggle-possible)

My code - It displays an iframe from a dynamically created link, when you click the button in the datatable column.

```js
$("#example tbody").on("click", "a.actions", function() {
  const id = $(this).attr('href');
  let clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    $('#' + id).css("display", "none");
  } else {
    $('#' + id).css("display", "block");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  let src = 'https://web02.datacentre.local/master-database/master-task-view-actions/entry/' + id;
  $('#' + id).attr('src', src);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div.d1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>

<div class="d1" style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;width:250px">
  <p><b>This is a little poem: </b><br/> Twinkle, twinkle, little star<br/> How I wonder what you are<br/> Up above the world so high<br/> Like a diamond in the sky<br/> Twinkle, twinkle little star<br/> How I wonder what you are</p>
</div>
```